# What's the difference between commands cat /etc/group & groups & getent group

Tags: unix

I am a novice Unix user and was wondering where all the groups are stored in Unix. I thought that they would be updated in `/etc/group` file but when I read that file it does not have everything. Whereas, `getent group` command displays all the groups and associated users in each group.

I am aware that each user has a primary group, which will be stored in `/etc/passwd` (usually in field 4), and may have one or more supplementary groups. Only the supplementary group associations are in `/etc/group`

So, here are my questions.

1. Am I under the wrong impression that all groups are stored in `/etc/group` ?
2. If so, what is the difference between these three commands 
   a. `cat /etc/group`
   b. `groups`
   c. `getent group`
3. Why am I able to see more groups when I use the command `getent groups` than `cat /etc/group` ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getent` reads from `/etc/groups` and whatever other database sources are configured for your system. For a Solaris system, this is stored in SMF:

```
$ svcprop -p config name-service/switch 
config/automount astring files\ ldap
config/default astring files
config/group astring files\ ldap
config/host astring files\ dns
config/netgroup astring ldap
config/password astring files\ ldap
config/value_authorization astring solaris.smf.value.name-service.switch
```

For a linux system, have a look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf`